# How to update Video component in gradio?

Tags: python, gradio

I want to display a different video in the gr.components.Video() after the button is clicked.

```
def update_video(input_video):
    video = input_video.replace('.mp4', '_out.mp4')
    return [gr.components.Video.update(value=video)]

with gr.Blocks(theme=gr.themes.Soft()) as interface: 
    inputs = gr.components.Video()
    update = gr.Button('Update')

    update.click(update_video, inputs=inputs, outputs=[inputs])

interface.launch(height=700)
```

Tried the code above it results in an empty video box.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: @LoganPrice

Nope, now I even do believe that it is impossible (at least the way I want it)

Answer (score 2):

Running your code, uploading an `.mp4` video file and clicking on the `Update` button results in the following exception:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Video' has no attribute 'update'
```

This is most likely because you are using a recent version of Gradio. In Gradio 4.0, the `update()` method was removed (see [Gradio 4.0 changelog](https://www.gradio.app/changelog#:%7E:text=Removes%20the%20deprecated%20.update()%20method%20from%20component%20classes))

---

### Updating Components

The recommended way for updating components is now to [have your event listener function return the updated value of the corresponding output Component](https://www.gradio.app/guides/blocks-and-event-listeners#updating-component-configurations). This might not really be necessary for your use case though. For the full details, check out the `Passing Input Into a Component Normally` section of this answer.

Modifying your code to accomodate the reccomended method of updating Gradio components:

```py
import shutil
import gradio as gr

def update_video(input_video):
    old_video_path = input_video
    new_video_path = input_video.replace('.mp4', '_out.mp4')

    # Replace shutil.copyfile with whatever processing you are doing
    shutil.copyfile(old_video_path, new_video_path)

    # Return the updated video component. 
    # You only need to specify in the arguments the things you wish to
    # change. In this case we're only interested in the `value` but 
    # it can also be `label`, `scale`, `visibility` et cetera
    return gr.Video(value=new_video_path)

with gr.Blocks(theme=gr.themes.Soft()) as interface:
    # gr.components.Video is equivalent to gr.Video
    inputs = gr.Video()
    update = gr.Button('Update')

    update.click(update_video, inputs=inputs, outputs=[inputs])

interface.launch(height=700)
```

Just make sure that as you're modifying the path of the video file, the new path points to a valid video file that can be played.

---

### Passing Input Into a Component Normally

However, in the first place, you don't actually need to explicitly update the `gr.Video` component.

In the `update.click` event listener, you are already passing the output of the `update_video` event listener function into the `inputs` `gr.Video` component.

```py
update.click(
    update_video, # The event listener function
    inputs=inputs, # Where inputs into `update_video` come from
    outputs=[inputs] # Where output from `update_video` will go.
                     # It can be either be what the `inputs` `gr.Video` 
                     # component expects as input, or it can be an 
                     # update for the `inputs` `gr.Video` component
)
```

Because of that, you'll be able to replicate the same behaviour as above by just retuning the modified filepath in your `update_video` event listener function like so:

```py
import shutil
import gradio as gr

def update_video(input_video):
    old_video_path = input_video
    new_video_path = input_video.replace('.mp4', '_out.mp4')

    # Replace shutil.copyfile with whatever processing you are doing
    shutil.copyfile(old_video_path, new_video_path)

    # Simply return the new video path
    return new_video_path

with gr.Blocks(theme=gr.themes.Soft()) as interface:
    # gr.components.Video is equivalent to gr.Video
    inputs = gr.Video()
    update = gr.Button('Update')

    update.click(update_video, inputs=inputs, outputs=[inputs])

interface.launch(height=700)
```